# Программа для парсинга текста с новостных сайтов

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, tkinter, bs4

Здравствуйте.

Пишу программу для парсинга сайта https://www.fontanka.ru/, есть вот такой код:

```
import requests
rs = requests.get('http://www.fontanka.ru/2018/04/12/086/')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

article = root.select_one('article')
print(article.text)
# print(article.text[:100])
```

Функционал данной программы меня устраивает за одним исключением. Я пытаюсь написать интерфейс для того чтобы вбивать туда ссылку на сайт, а затем она обрабатывалась парсером и выдавала результат. Но никак не могу заставить в requests обработать ссылку из интерфейса.
Сам алгоритм работы такой: запускается интерфейс с полем ввода и двумя кнопками->пользователь вводит ссылку в поле ввода->нажимаем ОК(или печать)->ссылка копируется в request->текст статьи выводится в консоль->проверяем правильность->нажимаем кнопку выход для выхода из программы.
Графический модуль писал с помощью Tkinter.

```
import requests, bs4, tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *

class App(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.var.set('Enter url')
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Enter:')
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button_ok = tkinter.Button(self, text='Ok',             
command=self.press_button_ok)
    self.button_ok.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.button_quit = tkinter.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.master.destroy)
    self.button_quit.pack(side=LEFT)

    # второй фрейм для правильного выравнивания
    self.f = tkinter.Frame(self.master)
    self.f.pack(fill=BOTH)
    self.f.v = tkinter.StringVar()
    self.f.l = tkinter.Label(self.f, textvariable=self.f.v)
    self.f.l.pack(fill=X)

def press_button_ok(self):
        url=requests.get('http://www.fontanka.ru/2018/04/16/088/') #здесь должен быть захват url
            b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
        url1=b.select('article')
        url_print=url1[0].getText()
        print(url_print)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = App()
    root.master.title('Window')
    root.master.geometry('300x70+500+500')
    root.mainloop()
```

Вопрос лишь в том, что я делаю не так? Ибо я уже всю голову себе сломал как это сделать.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: нужно получить значение переменной, которая к полю url привязана - `url = requests.get(self.var.get())`

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.

Comment: @suit, мб оформите как ответ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения значения `tkinter.StringVar()`, которая привязана к вашему полю ввода, используется метод `get()`:

```
url = requests.get(self.var.get())
```